# Spring-cloud brixton, eureka and docker with ephemeral ports

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm using spring cloud eureka for microservice registration in a dockerised environment on aws.

As i'm using dockers ephemeral port mapping the port exposed on the container host is unknown. To overcome that i've a custom `EurekaInstanceConfigBean` that asks the docker daemon on the host for the assigned port so i can use that to register with eureka.

That all works fine until registration starts. The `EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration` contains a `@EventListener(EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent.class)` that overrides the external port i've assigned in my custom `EurekaInstanceConfigBean` and sets it back to the local port inside the container.

I think the listeners purpose is to support auto port assignment in case of `server.port=0` but in my setup it's breaking things.

The question is: Can i somehow stop the `EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration` to override my manually set port? Can i somehow use my own `EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use host networking and thus the docker container uses the network stack of the host which makes the service accessible on it's IP addresses.

I used this by utilizing docker-compose. The services all have random ports despite the edge services which are working as reverse proxy (in my case zuul based). these edge services have stable ports.

Comment: Hi Patrick, my problem is setting the port in the config bean so i can register with eureka. Either way, i've now overwritten the `EurekaInstanceConfigBean` with a version that ignores `setNonSecurePort` and exposes an alternative setter - that works but feels way to hackish...